# error: no suitable method found for select(String,ArrayList<String>,int,int)

Tags: java

My class can't see my method `select`:

```
public void select(String tableName, ArrayList<String> columns , int startOfLimit , int endOfLimit) {

        query = "SELECT "+columns.get(0) ;

        for (int i = 1; i < columns.size(); i++)
            query += " , "+columns.get(i);

        query += " FROM "+tableName+" ";
        super.conditions += " LIMIT " + startOfLimit + " , " + endOfLimit;
        selectExecute();
    }
```

it give me this error:

> no suitable method found for `select(String, ArrayList<String>, int, int)`

when I call it

```
sql.select("user", array, 1, 2);
```

// the variable array is an arraylist

Comment: post the full code where you are invoking the method please. What is the type of "sql" ?

Comment: sql is a object from class Sql , the method select from class Sql

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I don’t think we can help you as the question stands. Consider posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and there will be a really great chance that we can.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that both are different classes. Making that select function static will solve your problem.

Comment: I think we know far from enough to know whether nor how this could help. Static methods usually have their own issues, and most definitely a better solution is available here. We just cannot tell which from the information provided in the question.